# How to open a new script in the same tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have the code

```
window.open("http://localhost/xyz.php")
```

This opens the PHP file on a new tab, although the same window. I want to open this on the same tab. How do I do it.

I have tried `window.open("http://localhost/xyz.php","_self")` and `window.open("http://localhost/xyz.php";"_self")` but that does not work. I have also tried `window.location.href`but nothing seems to work. Is there any other way?

Comment: `ẁindow.location = 'url';`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `window.location` object:

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost/xyz.php';
```

Changing [href](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) property, changes the current page address to the one you give as a parameter...

*Note: you could also use `window.location = 'http://localhost/xyz.php';`, as suggested in comment, which is a bit shorter; though, changing location.href is a bit more standard, being implemented since JavaScript 1.0, so it's available in all browsers...*

Comment: This does not work. I have tried this already. the problem when I use this, is that it does not open the PHP page at all.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
window.location.replace("http://localhost/xyz.php");
```

Comment: I didn't know (the specifics of) this technique. Worth noting that, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace), this will have special effect on the browser history.

Comment: @vinayakj Could you elaborate on how this does not attempt to answer the question?

Comment: @Jeroen this is very unsecure way to open something in same tab.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript) .

It is a decision of the user, not the programmer, if a new page is opened in a new tab or a new window.

Comment: OP wants to open the new page in the **same** tab, so I suppose she just wants to change location...

Answer (score -1):

Try use this in your js:

`location.href = "http://localhost/xyz.php";`